# Saving a webpage along with its gifs

Tags: webpage, gif, save-as

I'm looking for a way to save a wepgage along with its gifs ([example](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Advanced_Classical_Mechanics/Phase_Space)).

I know how to save a single gif, but my goal is to save the whole webpage (not as a pdf) and its gifs so that, when I open the file, I can see text and gifs.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome extension: [Save Page WE](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-page-we/dhhpefjklgkmgeafimnjhojgjamoafof/related)